# Ho do I use CKEditor's focusManager class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I'm currently writing a js script that changes some styles around in order to hide a fixed footer and position a header absolutely when using a touch device.
I've been able to successfully implement it with normal text input fields and textareas, but since CKEditor doesn't parse in the DOM as a textarea, I'm forced to use it's focusManager class in order to trigger the change when the user focuses on an instance of it in my site.
The problem is that I've never used CKEditor's API before and I'm having some problems using it's focusManager class after doing some research.

Below is my current script.
It works fine for textareas and text inputs, but not on CKEditor.
From what I understand, where you see "cke_1", that is the instance name of the editor, but it's not working.
Also, I have multiple instances of CKEditor throughout my site and it needs to work on all of them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
var focusManager = new CKEDITOR.focusManager(cke_1); 
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.cke_1;

$(document)
.on("focus", "input", function(e) {
    $body.addClass('fix');
    $('footer').hide();
})
.on("blur", "input", function(e) {
    $body.removeClass('fix');
    $('footer').show();
});

$(document).on("focus", "textarea", function(e){
    $body.addClass('fix');
    $('footer').hide();
})
.on("blur", "textarea", function(e){
    $body.removeClass('fix');
    $('footer').show();
});

$(document).on("focus", editor.focusManager, function(e){
    $body.addClass('fix');
    $('footer').hide();
})
.on("blur", editor.focusManager, function(e){
    $body.removeClass('fix');
    $('footer').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working.  Since I have multiple instances of ckeditor, I wrote a function that is called when an instance is created and the user is on a mobile device.  This is how I did it:

```
function renderMobile(){

console.log("Mobile device detected");

// Set focus and blur listeners for all editors to be created.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function() {

    var editor;
    for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i];
    }
    var $body = CKEDITOR.document.getBody();

    editor.on('focus', function() {
        $body.addClass( 'fix' );
    });

    editor.on('blur', function() {
        $body.removeClass( 'fix' );
    });
});
}
```

Comment: This is running multiple times. Do you know any fix to this issue?

Comment: What do you mean it's running multiple times?  It's only a function so you only have to call it whenever you need to.

Comment: Okay thanks. Also, I didn't got the reason for setting `editor` inside the `for` loop. It will always set to the last instance of `CKEDITOR`. So, ideally, the focus / blur should apply only to last instance.

Comment: Well, theoretically that may be true, but it worked, I can tell you that :).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `focusManager` class at all. Simply listen on [`editor#focus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-focus) and [`editor#blur`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/LNP6p/)):

```
// Set focus and blur listeners for all editors to be created.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    var editor = evt.editor,
        body = CKEDITOR.document.getBody();

    editor.on( 'focus', function() {
        // Use jQuery if you want.
        body.addClass( 'fix' );
    } );

    editor.on( 'blur', function() {
        // Use jQuery if you want.
        body.removeClass( 'fix' );
    } );    
} );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar',
    on: {
        // Focus and blur listeners can be set per-instance,
        // if needed.
        // focus: function() {},
        // blur: function() {}
    }
} );
```

Comment: This still isn't working.  It's not getting inside my focus function nor blur for that matter.  Thoughts?